# Find optimal redistribution in flow graph

Tags: graphs, network-flow

I have directed graph (maybe with cycles), and some resources in vertices (let's say gold). I can transfer gold between vertices only in direction of edges. The task is to minimize maximum value of resources in vertices (e.g. make optimal redistribution of gold).

For example,
[image]
Optimal distribution for this graph is following:

6 => 5 => 5 => 5

So the answer is 6.

Or another example:

[image]

The answer is 9.

I think that solution should be based on finding max flow in graph and binary search for answer, but I can't connect these approaches and build proper solution. Could you please help?

Comment: Thanks for reply! In acyclic case should I make topological sort and check the possibility of collecting amount of gold less than given threshold t for every vertex in topological order?

Comment: Sorry, I found counterexample. Probably I'm missing something.. I'm still stuck on how to apply max flow algorithm even to acyclic graph case..

Comment: Your inital idea of solving a kind of max-flow was good. You should find an elegant solution working on the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. But I probably think to a different solution than D.W.